# How to create a rotate 3D Animation between a ListView and an ImageView in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to make a roate 3D Animation between a ListView and an ImageVIew in Android,Is there any library or sample code for that? I am new in Android development, so I don't know how to animate such thing.

Answer (score 0):

This library may help you : https://github.com/nipun-birla/Swipe3DRotateView

As mentioned in usage

Add dependency in your build.gradle(app)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.nipun-birla:Swipe3DRotateView:0.0.1'
}
```

Put Swipe3DRotateView in your layout as required :

```
<com.nipunbirla.swipe3drotateview.Swipe3DRotateView
    android:id="@+id/rotateView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    //Put the backview as first child
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#934567">
    </FrameLayout>

    //Put the frontview as second child
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#134567">
    </FrameLayout>

</com.nipunbirla.swipe3drotateview.Swipe3DRotateView>
```

Find view in your activity as :

```
Swipe3DRotateView swipe3DRotateView = findViewById(R.id.rotateView);
```

To set if X Rotation is allowed :

```
swipe3DRotateView.setIsXRotationAllowed(true);
```

To set if Y Rotation is allowed :

```
swipe3DRotateView.setIsYRotationAllowed(true);
```

To check if X Rotation is allowed :

```
boolean isXAllowed = swipe3DRotateView.isXRotationAllowed();
```

To check if Y Rotation is allowed :

```
boolean isYAllowed = swipe3DRotateView.isYRotationAllowed();
```

To set Animation duration, default value is 1000 millis

```
swipe3DRotateView.setAnimationDuration(1000);
```

To set animation listener on view up front, use :

```
swipe3DRotateView.setHalfAnimationCompleteListener(halfListener);
```

To set animation listener on view at back, use :

```
swipe3DRotateView.setCompleteAnimationCompleteListener(fullListener);
```